# messageBag with array L5.1

Tags: arrays, forms, validation, laravel-5

I'm getting this error message bag from a RESTfull API on a Laravel client, I want to show the errors to the user, but I'm having trouble to show the errors inside the bag when they are an array.

```
MessageBag {#251 ▼
  #messages: array:6 [▼
    "gender" => array:1 [▶]
    "first_name" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The first name must be at least 2 characters."
    ]
    "last_name" => array:1 [▶]
    "user_id" => array:1 [▶]
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "user_id" => array:1 [▶]
      "address2" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "The address2 must be at least 3 characters."
      ]
      "zip" => array:1 [▶]
      "phone" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "user_id" => array:1 [▶]
      "address2" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "The address2 must be at least 3 characters."
      ]
      "zip" => array:1 [▶]
      "phone" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

I know the normal way to show errors for example to print the gender errors I can do this one:

```
{!! $errors->first('gender', '<label class="control-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu"></i> :message</label>') !!}
```

Or to check if 'gender' error exists:

```
{!! $errors->has('gender') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}
```

But how I do to check if the array 0 exists and show the errors?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently on Laravel 5.1 printing MessageBags with Arrays is not posible, my solution was to instance a different MessageBag for the secondary errors instead of nest it on the main MessageBag.

Another posible solution was to nest it like:

```
MessageBag {#251 ▼
  #messages: array:6 [▼
    "gender" => array:1 [▶]
    "first_name" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The first name must be at least 2 characters."
    ]
    "last_name" => array:1 [▶]
    "user_id.0.errors" => array:1[▼
      0 => "True"
    ] 
    "user_id.0.error_name" => array:1[▼
      0 => "The first name must be at least 2 characters"
    ] 
    "user_id.1.errors" => array:1[▼
      0 => "True"
    ] 
    "user_id.1.error_name" => array:1[▼
      0 => "The first name must be at least 2 characters"
    ] 
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

But is not a clean way to do it, as I said, create  a secondary MessageBag was more clean and easy :)